# Write tests for Visual Studio extensions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-extensions

I have written an extension for VS 2017 but I can't seem to find how to write tests for it.

Can someone please refer me to a resource explain how to test the extension?

Answer (score 3):

See for example [VisualStudio-TestHost](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudio-TestHost) and [VsixTesting](https://github.com/josetr/VsixTesting) projects.